# c# catch a ftp error

Tags: c#, ftp

How do I catch the ftp when it is unable to connect?  I tried this, but had no luck.

```
try
        {
        Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream file = File.OpenRead(this.txtFile.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to upload file! Please close out window and try again later. " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Error   2   The name 'file' does not exist in the current context

Error   3   The name 'ftpStream' does not exist in the current context

Warning 1   The variable 'Chosen_File' is assigned but its value is never used

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: See DBM's answer - the exception isn't being thrown by any code posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is because you are trying to use the variables `ftpStream` and `file` outside of the `try {}` block. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) some reading from MSDN on the subject of try/catch blocks.